# Form fields are not shown in django templates, only submit button

Tags: python, django, django-forms

**Hello everybody!!! I have a problem with forms, below is the code, any help will be appreciated...**

views.py

```
def my_registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                        first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                                        last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                                        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                        password=form.cleaned_data['password'],)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[user.id]))

    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = MyForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('register.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my forms.py which works fine

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

and here is my forms.py when it is replaced, stopped showing the fields.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

here is the register.html

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: When i run this code, in the browser I cannot see the fields, Only submit button.

Comment: What's in register.html? Can you share the contents of that file as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace forms.Form with forms.ModelForm. This should work.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example you have not mentioned `forms.typeField` , Look in the below example:

For you Html page some thing like this:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

In forms.py you should have fields

```
form.py
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

For more examples and references look into :
[Django working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/)

Comment: yes you are right and as you said that way works fine, but I wanted to try by using class Meta, where you just type name of the model and fields.

Comment: my reputation does not let me, still granted bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

return render_to_response('register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

form is not coming for sure... instead dict as object let's do one iteration like this...

Comment: you mean HttpResponseRedirect must be replaced by the code that you wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

form = MyForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':

This is logical error your form should be top.